# How to Join two related tables, while a record in one, refers to two records in the other?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a transactions table with sender_id and receiver_id fields, and another users table with user_id first_name last_name etc...

I want to query data from the transaction and join details from the users
thing is I need to bring first_name & last_name for both sender and receiver...

```
SELECT t.* u.*
FROM transactions t, users u
WHERE t.sender_id = u.user_id OR t.receiver_id = u.user_id
```

This will not be a solution of course since I have no way for knowing in the result-set which is the sender / receiver, but it helps illustrate the problem

any ideas?
thanks
Ajar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join table `users` twice on table `transactions` since there are two column from transaction which are dependent on table `users`.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.firstName as SenderName,
        c.FirstName as RecieverName
FROM    transactions a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.sender_ID = b.user_ID
        INNER JOIN users c
            ON a.reciever_id = c.user_ID
```